# Annotate Percent stacked barchart in the middle of each class, ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, tidyverse

I have this data:

```
structure(list(filter = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("no filtering, (523)", 
"p3 <= 2 mm, (421)", "p3 <= 5 mm, (384)", "p3 <= 10 mm, (337)"
), class = "factor"), conti = c("False Negative", "False Positive", 
"True Negative", "True Positive", "False Negative", "False Positive", 
"True Negative", "True Positive", "False Negative", "False Positive", 
"True Negative", "True Positive", "False Negative", "False Positive", 
"True Negative", "True Positive"), n = c(26L, 476L, 47L, 497L, 
15L, 173L, 248L, 406L, 23L, 102L, 282L, 361L, 33L, 68L, 269L, 
304L), share = c(0.0248565965583174, 0.455066921606119, 0.0449330783938815, 
0.475143403441683, 0.0178147268408551, 0.205463182897862, 0.294536817102138, 
0.482185273159145, 0.0299479166666667, 0.1328125, 0.3671875, 
0.470052083333333, 0.0489614243323442, 0.100890207715134, 0.399109792284866, 
0.451038575667656)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), groups = structure(list(
    filter = structure(1:4, .Label = c("no filtering, (523)", 
    "p3 <= 2 mm, (421)", "p3 <= 5 mm, (384)", "p3 <= 10 mm, (337)"
    ), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1:4, 5:8, 9:12, 
        13:16), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

which with the following code produces this "Percent stacked barchart":

```
ggplot(contis) +
  geom_bar(
    aes(
      y = filter,
      x = n,
      fill = conti
    ),
    stat = "identity",
    position = "fill"
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      x = share,
      y = filter,
      label = round(share, 2)
    )
  )
```

[image]

Now the annotations are completely wrong and I am a little lost how I could achieve this.
I would like the share of each class to be roughly (for the very small ones it is impossible) in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding labels to bar charts you have to set the right `position` argument, as `geom_bar` or `geom_col` use `position="stack"` by default whereas `geom_text` uses `position="identity"`:

Hence, to get the labels stacked add `position = position_stack()` to geom_text. Additionally to place the labels in the middle of the bars use `vjust = .5`. Finally, you have to tell ggplot about the grouping which in your case is the variable mapped on `fill`. To this end add `group=conti`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(contis) +
  geom_bar(
    aes(
      y = filter,
      x = n,
      fill = conti
    ),
    stat = "identity",
    position = "fill"
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      x = share,
      y = filter,
      label = round(share, 2),
      group = conti,
    ),
    position = position_stack(vjust = .5)
  )
```

However, you could simplify your code a bit by setting aesthetics inside `ggplot()` like so:

```r
ggplot(contis, aes(share, filter, fill = conti)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(share, 2)), position = position_stack(vjust = .5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! I rarely use the `position`-argument as I am not 100 % aware of its meaning. But I certainly will try to read up on what this actually makes